# Could python code working be frozen with some window power saving option?

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium

I leave a question asking if anyone knows.
I am collecting some data every day through crawling. (with python selenium lib) In the state of infinite repetition in the form of threading.Thread(target= Function), after going to work, turning around for an hour and a half, and then in a completely freeze state, I went home and moved the mouse to turn on the screen. It restarts as if nothing happened again. (It stops at a certain line of code and then wakes up with mouse movement)
Could it have something to do with Windows' power saving options?
According to the records, it was confirmed that when the movement was performed every 10 minutes, it worked well from 9:30 am to 11:00 am, and then started working again from the time the mouse was moved at 7:30 pm.
All power saving modes in the power management options are disabled...
In advanced power management options
Turn off the hard disk = 20 minutes (presumed not to be the cause because it is shorter than an hour and a half)
Off state of all power saving options
Display off = 5 minutes

Comment: Maybe selenium stops when the screensaver is activated

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

**Run your code in Headless Browser Mode:**

```
#Way to create Headless Chrome Browser driver
ch_Options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    ch_Options.add_argument('--headless')
    ch_Options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('..\drivers\chromedriver',options=ch_Options)
Now your script will execute in lock / sleep / hibernate all states.
```

**Run in lock state not in Sleep/Hibernate State:**

If you still want to run in normal browser then lock your screen before it goes in Sleep / Hibernate state as selenium will keep executing in lock state. Also set Display turn off to -> Never turn off.